# Рекурсивная сумма

Tags: рекурсия, prolog, swi-prolog

Язык: Swi Prolog. Надо сделать сумму так, чтобы прибавлялось по 1.

Немного набросал

```
add(A, B, F) :-
F = F+1,
not(A+B = F) ->  add(A, B, F).
```

Но оно не работает

> ?- X = 0, add(20, 5, X).
>
> false

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: а что должна делать строчка: `not(A+B = F) ->  add(A, B, F)`?

Comment: Ну если сумма левого и правого числа не равны выходному значению, то запускаем эту же функцию, где плюсуем её

Answer (score 0):

> Что я не так делаю?

```
add(A, B, F) :-
F = F+1,
not(A+B = F) ->  add(A, B, F).
```

1. Вы путаете **Унификацию** с присваиванием в императивных языках;
2. В Прологе вложенные выражения (функции) в общем случае не вычисляются;
3. Функции вычисляются предикатами, которые "умеют" это делать;
4. ->/2 "если то" предикат.

```
add( A, B, C ) :-
   add0( A0, B0, C0 ),
   A is A0, 
   B is B0,
   C is C0.

add0( A, 0, A).
add0( 0, A, A).
add0( A+1, B, C+1 ) :-
   add0( A, B, C).
add0( A, B+1, C+1 ) :-
   add0( A, B, C).
```

Comment: что-то я не понял последнюю строку. в ней же нет рекурсии, сразу вычисляется `C is A + B`? Да и A1 вычисляется, но нигде не используется дальше

Comment: все равно неверно: если A и B не 0 - то будет бесконечная рекурсия, потому что A увеличивается, а B не изменяется

Answer (score 0):

В прологе на запрос `?- X = 1 + 2.` система ответит `X = 1 + 2`. Для вызова арифметических операций нужно использовать операцию `is`:

```
?- X is 1 + 2. 
X = 3
```

Операция `=` - это операция сопоставления, она не вызывает вычисление арифметических выражений, но может согласовать переменные. Для сравнения равенства арифметических выражений используется операция `=:=`

Ну а рекурсивную сумму можно записать в виде следующего набора предложений:

```
sum(Augend, 0, Augend) :- !.
sum(Augend, Addend, Result):-
    Addend >= 0, !,
    NewAddend is Addend - 1,
    sum(Augend, NewAddend, NewResult),
    Result is NewResult + 1.

sum(Augend, Addend, Result):-
    Addend < 0,
    NewAddend is Addend + 1,
    sum(Augend, NewAddend, NewResult),
    Result is NewResult - 1.
```

Здесь первое предложение отвечает за конец рекурсии, второе и третье за сам расчет суммы в зависимости от знака второго слагаемого. Правда для корректной работы данного предиката переменные `Augend` и `Addend` должны быть конкретизированы.